# Deploy deb файла в Apt Repository Nexus 3

Tags: repository, apt, deb, nexus

Всем привет! Сгенерировал gpg ключ, создал apt репозиторий, прописал туда id ключа. Nexus запущен в докере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь залить в репозиторий deb файл

```bsh
curl -u "admin:admin123" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" --data-binary "@./roschat_0.1.1143_amd64.deb" "http://10.10.199.217:8080/repository/roschat-client.deb/"
```

Но получаю в ответ ошибку

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>500 - Nexus Repository Manager</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>


  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script>(new Image).src="http://10.10.199.217:8080/favicon.ico?3.23.0-03"</script>
  <![endif]-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://10.10.199.217:8080/favicon-32x32.png?3.23.0-03" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="mask-icon" href="http://10.10.199.217:8080/safari-pinned-tab.svg?3.23.0-03" color="#5bbad5">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://10.10.199.217:8080/favicon-16x16.png?3.23.0-03" sizes="16x16">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://10.10.199.217:8080/favicon.ico?3.23.0-03">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="http://10.10.199.217:8080/mstile-144x144.png?3.23.0-03">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#00a300">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://10.10.199.217:8080/static/css/nexus-content.css?3.23.0-03"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nexus-header">
  <a href="http://10.10.199.217:8080">
    <div class="product-logo">
      <img src="http://10.10.199.217:8080/static/images/nexus.png?3.23.0-03" alt="Product logo"/>
    </div>
    <div class="product-id">
      <div class="product-id__line-1">
        <span class="product-name">Nexus Repository Manager</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-id__line-2">
        <span class="product-spec">OSS 3.23.0-03</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

<div class="nexus-body">
  <div class="content-header">
    <img src="http://10.10.199.217:8080/static/rapture/resources/icons/x32/exclamation.png?3.23.0-03" alt="Exclamation point" aria-role="presentation"/>
    <span class="title">Error 500</span>
    <span class="description">Internal Server Error</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content-body">
    <div class="content-section">
      java.io.IOException: unknown object in stream: 16
    </div>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Попробовал загрузить файл через web, получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуй pbezpal. Исходя из скриншота, что у вас указан в настройках Nexus, **Signing Key** поле заполнено не верно. В это поле нужно вставить контент приватного ключа, а не ID как в вашем случае.
**Пример:**

```
-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----

lQVYBF8MzdsBDAC+5E1TpZXgAohiOYcdA9DUkMs++5L0KZcSiEDY9X5i+IqRnJkd
ErZYx0C3dJzpHjUx0bTajyXcGP4Mbq5qAPAEhJvav3AR/9gMMWCsmL66yhbzMkLR
...
DScPryrIzM3EG3r39NkLnQi8wz1ZYpodFMLyChhj5mPoT/H+h81F1QEf1QvV72Fy
xrTSJfL9Btg4Vy+g3Uh1fo0hLhqU36pFNnmoaWu90uRc
=53GK
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
```

Убедись, что контент скопирован с всеми хедерами, отступами и переносами. Иначе ключ будет не валидный.
Удачи!

Comment: Спасибо большое. В поддержке Nexus ответили тоже самое. Сгенерировать ключ удалось в самом докер контейнере. Только предварительно нужно было доустановить pinentry. И всё заработало) Спасибо Вам большое)